# Part doesn't gives damage, Touch event

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I made a code but it didn't worked, i tried to change the code but no success. How i can do this? I want to give damage without giving damage to the player. Code here

```
hitpunch.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
                if hit.Parent:IsA("Model") and hit.Parent.Name == "Boss" and debounceDMG == true then
                    debounceDMG = false
                    hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health -= Player:GetAttribute("Forca")
                    task.wait(.1)
                    debounceDMG = true
                end
            end)
```

Comment: We need more details. What is the initial value of `debounceDMG`? Any errors? Where did you define `Player` in?

Comment: No errors. The initial value is true and the Player is defined by a RemoteEvent fired by a client.

Comment: So as far as I can understand, you want this part to damage something (not the player) when the player touches it. Is that correct?

Comment: No, its like a punch, i want to damage the dummy or the enemy

Comment: So your goal is to have it damage any non-players? Since the code right now will only damage a character / dummy named "Boss"

Comment: The boss dont get damaged, but i fixed the code and it worked, but isn't by the name.